# Filter, Subseting Data in R

Tags: r, filter, subset, dplyr

I have a reference table where I have peoples Names and attributes (Bad Emails)

I wish to subset the table based on peoples names below

I have tried two ways to deal with this

```
# Returns nothing
subset(bad.email, User.Name %in% c('John'))
filter(bad.email, User.Name %in% 'John')

# returns what im looking for
subset(bad.email, grepl("John", User.Name ))
filter(bad.email, grepl("John", User.Name ))
```

Can anyone explain why this may be the case?

In the end i want to replace john with a column from a reference table but i just wish to wrap my head around the concept first

Comment: It means that you have leading/lagging spaces in the columns. Try `library(stringr); bad.email$User.Name <- str_trim(bad.email$User.Name)` and your code should work

Comment: Hi @akrun. I attempted this previously and i also set strip.white=TRUE when importing the file so I'm not sure as to why nothing is returned

Comment: I am not sure either without a reproducible example.  It was a guess based on what you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your time, As a work around i guess i can collapse the reference table into a string splitting it based on '|' and feed that into the grep.

Comment: `%in%` returns an exact match while `grepl` returns `TRUE` for whenever a certain string contains this specific pattern. Different things. Compare `"a" == "aa" ; grepl("a", "aa")`

Comment: @David Arenburg Ah OK, so if there is a Sir name in the field i am looking at %in% will always return nothing because its not an exact match including capitalization of letters etc ?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right.

Comment: Yes on testing against my data set that is the case. Please submit it as an answer and i will mark it as an answer. Thank you @akrun also for your help

Comment: Btw, `grepl` is also sensitive to case, so you'll need to use the `ignore.case` parameter for such cases, either way, you can submit an answer yourself if you wish

Answer (score 2):

Based on feedback from @akrun and @David Arenburg

The reason the first two lines of code potentially failing to work is there may be white space in the field.
White space can be removed by setting the strip.white=TRUE when initially reading the file in. Alternatively using the str_trim(col_name) from the stringr library will also do it

The second reason is the main reason my code didn't work which was the %in% matches exactly the pattern you are looking for.

In my case there were surnames in the field and i was only matching on first name. To fix this either match by the whole name or match using grepl. grepl is case sensitive so adding the option to ignore.case is true will match the fields while ignoring the case

```
# remove whitespace
bad.email$User.Name <- str_trim(bad.email$User.Name)

# returns what im looking for using %in%
subset(bad.email, User.Name %in% c('John Smith'))
filter(bad.email, User.Name %in% 'John Smith')

# returns what im looking for using grepl
subset(bad.email, grepl("John Smith", User.Name, ignore.case = TRUE ))
filter(bad.email, grepl("John Smith", User.Name, ignore.case = TRUE ))
```